# RelativeLayout is shown on the Devicescreen of AndroidStudio but not on Emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background, android-relativelayout

I am working on an Android Studio Project. I want to include a `Fragment` on the Bottom of the screen. So far so good, it works and is shown. But when I want to show a `RelativeLayout` on top, it is not shown on the emulator but is shown on the device screen of Android Studio. I need the layout to create a background only at the top of the screen. Are there any mistakes in my code, or are there other ways to create the background?

This is my XML-code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#000">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.htlhl.listfragment.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="197dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <!--The following RelativeLayout is not shown at the top-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="#00632e"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio]

Emulator and real device:

[image: Emulator]

Comment: Can you provide the screenshots, both from the Android Studio and the device? You can edit your post to add more info to it.

Comment: I tried to run this on a real device  (Moto G 2) and its working fine in it.

Just dont rely on Emulator always, try to test this on a real device.

Comment: Thank u Maniya Joe, i will try it. If it is not working, I will post the screenshots for Aleksandar

Comment: Also on the real Device it is not shown.
 I added all Screenshots.
@AleksandarStefanović

Comment: Try moving the RelativeLayout above the fragment (in XML), so that the RelativeLayout appears first in the XML text, then the fragment. I'm not 100% positive that this is the issue, but it's worth trying.

Also, why are you using RelativeLayout and not LinearLayout? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: I am using the RelativeLayout because in the LinearLayout i am not able to place the Button on the Right side...maybe you could tell me how I can do this. Thank you

I tried to move the Fragment and it is not working...

Comment: @Goetti I meant as a parent layout (the one that holds all other layouts).

Comment: @ManiyaJoe Is the green rectangle shown on the Top of the screen with an height of 50dp? Because it is only shown with matchparent on my device

Comment: Sry I cant follow you with the Layout....But I found the mistake...If I take "Match Parent" instead of "50dp" as the hight of the RelativeLayout it is shown. What can I do to show it only with an hight of 50dp? Also "WrapContent" is not shown @AleksandarStefanović

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="#00632e"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.htlhl.listfragment.MyListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can further improve your layout, just tell me if this works.

Comment: Thanks, but now I really found the mistake, In my content_main.xml File the Layout is on the Top. The content_main.xml is included in the activity_main.xml -> But the include starts at the Top of the Screen and not below the Toolbar, so the Layout I am searching for is behind the Toolbar.     How can I move the iclude below the Toolbar?

Comment: If the parent layout of the <include> and <Toolbar> is the CoordinatorLayout, it handles it by itself (the issue should not be there). I'm guessing that, since you've set the dimensions to static DP, maybe you don't have enough space on your phone to display all the elements.

Comment: @Goetti, also, try my layout if you haven't, it's worth trying, maybe it will fix your issue.

Comment: If I set it to 70dp I can see around 15dp so 55dp are behind The toolbar...in my other Project the include starts below the toolbar and in this Project I want to use it finally...so it should not be a problem their

Comment: Then try to move the whole <include> tag below the Toolbar in the XML (just move the text below).

Comment: As i thought, in my real project it works fine. maybe one last question...how can i place the Textview in the vertical_center of a linearLayout? I can't find a usefull answer which works

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to align horizontally,
`android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to align vertically,
`android:layout_gravity="center"` to align both axes.

Comment: but the vertical-command do not work....it center horizontaly but not verticaly...it stays always left...even I set the gravity to right or end it stays left...

Comment: I posted it as an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#00632e"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:weightSum="1.0">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:text="Start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Its about the TextView...